# Issues resuming app with PickFolderAndContinue method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am having issues resuming my app after utilizing the PickFolderAndContinue method. I've been trying to go off the directions from [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba#content) MSDN sample. I haven't been able to figure out how to change the `OnActivated` method to return to my Settings page (the sample uses only the mainpage with different frames of content).

```
    protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        ContinuationManager continuationManager = new ContinuationManager();

        Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
        await RestoreStatusAsync(e.PreviousExecutionState);

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
        }

        var continuationEventArgs = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
        if (continuationEventArgs != null)
        {
            // What do i do here to return to my settings page?
            Frame scenarioFrame = SettingsPage.Current.FindName("ScenarioFrame") as Frame; 
            if (scenarioFrame != null)
            {
                // Call ContinuationManager to handle continuation activation 
                continuationManager.Continue(continuationEventArgs, scenarioFrame);
            }
        }

        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your OnActivated is called if you know you always want to go to the SettingsPage then all you need is this code:

```
   Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
    await RestoreStatusAsync(e.PreviousExecutionState);

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
    }
```

That code creates the applications root frame, and tells it to navigate to that specific page.

The code after this uses ContinuationManager.  This is a mechanism set up to call into the page to let it know it is coming back from a AndContinue method. This will allow the page to do any functionality to occur for that Page.

FilePicker also has a ContinuationData property which you can set prior to calling the AndContinue method.  This data is available in OnActivated via the IContinuationActivatedEventArgs.

This blog has a good description of the AndContinue Methods:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/05/08/using-the-andcontinue-methods-in-windows-phone-silverlight-8-1-apps.aspx